# How to do Alignment within string.Format in C#?

Tags: c#, string, format, alignment

I have this line of code in C#:

```
return string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8);
```

It draws its data from a text file and is output in a list box.
I want to justify half of it to the left and half to the right so in dream world this:

```
return string.Format("align=left({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4},) align=right ({5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11})", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8);
```

I have looked around but have no clue how to do it. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: A listbox has its own idea how to align text, string.Format() doesn't count.  Your question is unanswerable until you document what kind of ListBox class you use.

Comment: Aligned left in concern to what? Where is the text going to printed? HTML, Silverlight, console or Winforms

Comment: In general each character has a different width so aligning with spaces won't work unless you're forcing the listbox to use a monospaced font... you'd need to tabulate the data and for that we'd need a better example on what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10} | {1,5}", "Bill", 51));
```

You'll get "51" aligned to right on 5 characters.

More examples here: [Align String with Spaces](https://web.archive.org/web/20221014184153/https://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/).

For official reference, see [Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/txafckwd(v=vs.90))

Comment: https://www.csharp-examples.net/align-string-with-spaces/ resolves to a poker site on my PC

Comment: @DanMarshall, you can always use the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/), especially for old posts like this one

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, to use alignment with C#6 string interpolation + formatting, for a quick reference, write it like this:

```
float avg = 3.48f;
float peak = 5.00f;
$"in : {avg,5:F1} K/s | peak {peak,5:F1} K"

const int Indent = 5; // In which indent part can also refer variable
$"in : {avg,Indent:F1} K/s | peak {peak,Indent:F1} K"
```

Will yield

```
"in :   3.5 K/s | peak   5.0 K"
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated