# Formatting emails

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have data in dataset which I am loopping to build up data for the email the data is as follows but I am using the following to produce the email using tabs but it doesnt see very iffiencet i can only use plain text is their a better way to get it to format nicer like using the datatable sizes or something

[image]

```
    Dim dataForEmail As String = ""
    Dim msg As String = ""
    msg = "The Following Deliverys where processed for the Following Ordernumbers at " & DateTime.Now.ToString() & Chr(13)
    dataForEmail = "Order Number" & vbTab & "BarCode" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Description" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Brand" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Size" & vbTab & "Colour" & vbTab & "Price" & vbTab & "RRP" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "Qty" & Chr(13)
    Dim totalcost As Decimal
    If Not IsNothing(results) AndAlso Not IsNothing(results.Rows) _
    AndAlso results.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        For Each thisRow As DataRow In results.Rows
            CreateDeliveryIncFileForGemini(thisRow)
            totalcost = totalcost + thisRow.Item("RRPPrice")
            dataForEmail = dataForEmail & BuildReportFoEmail(thisRow)
            connection.ExecuteNonQuerySql(scriptBuilder.SetDeliveryStatus(2, 1, thisRow.Item("r3DeliveryId")))
        Next
        connection.ExecuteNonQuerySql(scriptBuilder.SetDeliveryStatus(1, 0))

        dataForEmail = dataForEmail & vbCrLf & "Total Price " & totalcost.ToString()
        SendEmailViaWebService(dataForEmail, cfb.EmailForDeliverys, cfb.FullNameForEmailSubject, msg)
    End If
    CloseConnection()
```

Comment: You mean you are storing this in a text file? If not, you can use a `listview` to have a way better formatting and functionality.

Comment: You probably want to right-justify some of the text. [How to do Alignment within string.Format c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579506/how-to-do-alignment-within-string-format-c) might have enough information for you.

Comment: @Arman this is just a plain format email how could i use a list view for that

Comment: I see. Why can't you use html tags for formatting?

Comment: @Arman its a pree setup webservices company policy just