# C# text align in listbox

Tags: c#, listbox, alignment

I have list box where I dynamically insert items. I want them to be aligned into "columns". I have this code to insert and align:

```
listbox1.Items.Add(reader2[1].ToString().PadRight(15) + numericUpDown1.Value.ToString() + "x".PadRight(10) + skupaj.ToString() + " €");
```

And this results into this: [image: listbox]

I also saw this method:

```
 var daa = String.Format("{0, 5} {1, 10}", name, price);
```

But I do not know how this works.

Comment: Here is a good answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579564/2777098

Comment: Well i tired that but its still doesn't align, no matter what numbers I put it, item with longer name will out align it self

Answer (score 0):

Use a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with it's [View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view(v=vs.110).aspx) property set to Details. Add columns to it with the editor and then add items to it:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("First column text");
item.SubItems.Add("Second column text");
// etc.
listView.Items.Add(item);
```

Comment: I need to use listbox