# How to print array with constant row space in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I am trying to print a jagged array with a some kind of 'constant row spacing' to make it more clear to read. Here's default output which I receive :

[image]

And I wish to receive something similar to this :

[image]

Here is my array printing code :

```
 for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < level; j++)
                    Console.Write(string.Format("{0}   ", matrix[i][j].ToString("0.00")));
                Console.Write(Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }
```

Any quick and simple way to reach this?

Comment: use `\t` instead of spaces. if its still not good for large numbers use `\t\t`.

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4579564/3276027) answer, it can be helfpul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example for padding with width of 5 to the left

```
string.Format("{0:-5}", matrix[i][j].ToString("0.00"))
```

You can see [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/padright) more options how you can pad with spaces