# Right justifying decimal array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, decimal

I have a Project for my c# programming class; writing a program that can read an employee file and a sales slip file and process the two. I have completed the 2 arrays I needed and they fill in nicely. My problem is when I go to print out the results in console mode. 
My arrays are of type decimal. I need to have all the numbers right justified at a certain position and the only way I know how to do so is with the function .PadRight/.PadLeft , which only work for strings I see. Is there any other way to do this or should I just Convert.ToString each value?

Comment: Do you have an example of some of your input and expected output? It may make it quite a bit easier to determine what would work best.

Comment: telling us vs showing us what you have in regards to where the issues are happening are 2 different things.. please show code where the unexpected is happening

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579506/how-to-do-alignment-within-string-format-c

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to output your values padded using the Console, you can simply format them using [Composite Formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) and it's [`{0,spaces-to-format}` syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx#Format_Brief) :

```
// Example array of decimals
var input = new decimal[]{ 12.24m, 199.99m, 1.0m, 42.42m, 100321.123m };
// Format each value to 10 digits
foreach(decimal d in input)
{
    // Format each value to 10 places (right-justfied)
    // You could alternatively use d.ToString("{0,10") 
    Console.WriteLine("{0,10}",d);
}
```

You can [see a working example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WORLiT) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty much looking at

```
decimal val = 10m;
//Or PadLeft
string formattedVal = val.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ');
```

Comment: this is what my code looks like for printing it to console.