# Can you print multiple lists in columns, with matching entries on the same lines? C#

Tags: c#, list, console-application

I am writing a simple payroll console app. Essentially I have four lists, payOwedList, hoursList, namesList, payRateList; I have the user enter values for all but the payOwedList which is simply the result of hoursList * payRateList. What I am wondering is if it's possible to print the lists in four columns from left to right.

```
Employees;     Hours Worked;     Pay Rate;     Pay Owed;
```

Comment: Not entirely relevant, but it would be much simpler to have a single list of `PayRollInfo` objects that store the name, rate, hours (the pay can then be generated).

Comment: Never tried it but looks like it’s possible to print a table in a console app: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1147879/Print-DataTable-to-Console-and-more

Comment: Although this exercise would be rather valuable some thirty years ago, when terminals and "green screens" were still relevant, there is no value in perfecting this skill these days. If you want to format a table, learn how to do a table in a windows forms API or with a WPF table. In addition to learning something relevant you'll build something that also looks like a program from the 21-st century :-)

Comment: What is a good resource for getting familiar with WPF?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's certainly possible - make a format line that defines the width of each column:

```
var data = new[] {
    new { Name="Hello", Hours=40, Rate=12M, Owed = 0M }
,   new { Name="World", Hours=30, Rate=20M, Owed = 100M }
,   new { Name="Fiz Buz, Jr.", Hours=44, Rate=8M, Owed = 80M }
};
foreach (var e in data) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}\t{1,4:####}\t{2,7:c}\t{3,10:c}", e.Name, e.Hours, e.Rate, e.Owed);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/OKYrYa)

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4579506/335858) for information on format strings.